# Can't check / uncheck checkbox after applying jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm not great with jQuery so please be easy on me.

I have this script:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".item").click(function() {
            if($(this).find("input").attr("checked")) {
                $(this).css("background-color", "#d1d1d1");
                $(this).find("input").removeAttr("checked");
            } else {
                $(this).css("background-color", "#03d100");
                $(this).find("input").attr("checked", "checked");
            }
        });
    });
```

Applied to this HTML:

```
<ul class="col-1">
    <li class="item">
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <label for="">Check Up</label>
        <span class="float-r">$19</span>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

This is working, for the most part. What I want is for the 'li' to be clicked on, have the background color change, and the checkbox inside of it to be set to 'checked'. This does that, but it does not allow me to actually click the checkbox itself and have it change to checked or unchecked.

I assume it is something in the script that I am doing incorrectly but I am not familiar enough with jQuery to know.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CMb4J/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".item").click(function() {

        var checkbox = $(this).find(":checkbox"),   // keep reference of checkbox
            checked = checkbox.is(":checked");      // check checkbox status
        if (checked) {
            $(this).css("background-color", "#d1d1d1");
        } else {
            $(this).css("background-color", "#03d100");
        }

        // change checkbox statr
        checkbox.prop("checked", !checked);

    });

    // bind click event  to checkbox
    // to trigger the click to li

    $('.item :checkbox').click(function() {
      $(this).parent('li').click();
    });

});
```

**[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/606/)**

Answer (score 1):

It's because your event is tied to the parent container, so when you click the checkbox you're also clicking the `li.item` so they cancel each other out. You could use `e.preventDefault()` for the checkbox, however, I just updated your class names in the JS Fiddle for a more appropriate and clear fix.

Updated fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CMb4J/1/).

Comment: Thanks. This helps me understand what the problem was exactly, but your fiddle isn't entirely what I need. The entire li should change color.

Comment: Sorry I rushed and didn't pay attention to the rest of the code, but I notice you have accepted another answer so all is well :)